# Html5 video on iPad Swallows Events. Using Vimeo

Tags: javascript, ipad, iframe, mobile-safari, html5-video

I have the same issue as this post here. [HTML5 Video Element on iPad doesn't fire onclick or touchstart events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803702/html5-video-element-on-ipad-doesnt-fire-onclick-or-touchstart-events)

I have forward and back buttons that overlay the video. When the video is playing on the Ipad, the Ipad uses it's own quicktime player. The problem is that, the player overrides any clicks on it and interprets them as video commands.

The solution on the other post was to disable the controls in the html5 Tag.

> The video element, on the iPad, will swallow events if you use the controls attribute. You have to provide your own controls if you want the element to respond to touch events.

I am however, embedding videos with Vimeos IFrame code.

Does anyone know of a way to remove the control properties on a vimeo video or maybe a way to scrape the video code out of the Iframe? That way I can, remove the controls property myself.

Regards.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Quicktime tends to hijack the entire area of the video tag meaning any overlaying buttons etc will not work. On iphones a simple hack is have a dummy player and hide the <video> element as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626700/html5-video-possible-to-place-regular-html-content-over-video


From what I've read its a bug with Quicktime. For me i just went with a design solution. The easiest option may be to redesign without the buttons outside of the player